# How to debug problems with the Divio app?

Tags: divio

I am trying to set up the Divio app on Win10 Pro.

I can launch the application, log in, select the workspace folder for my project, so the required dependencies should be fine.

However when I click on "Set up my project", then a new window is opened with a text "Preparing logs...", and an animated "hour-glass" appears next to the "Open Shell" button in the lower-left corner, but that's it. Everything hangs up at this point, and I can't figure out what's wrong. Restarted the computer and the app several times, but with same results.

Any ideas how to work out what is going wrong?

Comment: It's an Electron application, and uses Chromium for the interface. You can invoke its inspector as you would in Chrome itself, using control-shift-i. Does the console show you any errors?

Comment: Awesome! I would be happy to accept this as a correct answer :) It was very helpful @DanieleProcida! Thank you!! With the help of this, it turned out that I did have a missing share on my drive in Docker Desktop. After correcting it, now it works fine, although I have an other, unrelated error. Any suggestions for this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Kunt4mjZYb19mSEuT7lXD4McFab4_bFdbGeUSMdrIIw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Divio app is an [Electron](https://electronjs.org) application, and uses [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home) for the interface.

You can invoke its [Inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) as you would in Chrome itself, using `command`-`option`-`i` on Macintosh and `control`-`shift`-`i` on Linux and Windows.

The Inspector's *Console* tab will show any errors, and this will help understand what is happening internally. Typically, they will be errors related to the operating system in some way.