# Divio Windows App hangs at Preparing Logs

Tags: windows, divio

I have installed the WIndows 10 Divio App as per the Divio Tutorial but when I select setup a project it hangs at Preparing logs... in the shell on the desktop and cannot see logs are anyway to investigate this. I have tried the solution in this question here [How to debug problems with the Divio app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441960/how-to-debug-problems-with-the-divio-app)

However, this does not work, any help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this, I did it by following the guide here:
https://divio-cloud-developer-handbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/01-installation.html

Essentially installed everything via the command line and then once that was running I could then sync the Divio app to the project folder which in turn allowed me to use the Divio app. Total PITA but it worked :)